# how to filter elements that throw exception during stream map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, exception, java-stream

I was following the article https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/handling-checked-exceptions-in-java-streams for extracting a method into a method, in order to handle exceptions, and noticed the examples given only look clean since they don't actually compile because they miss a return statement.
Essentially I'm looking to have a parse method similar to this "divide" in the article example 3, but mine parses the list and in some scenarios it will throw errors log them and continue, like this:

```
public List<String> validator(List<String> values) {
    return values.stream()
        .map(this::parse)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
public String parse(String s){
    try{
         // returns something or throws exceptions
    } catch (Exception e ){
       log(e)
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see from this code I cheated the compilation error by returning a null at the end of the parse method that I then filter nulls on my validator before collecting, and it looks appalling. Is there a better way to skip the values in a clean easy way?

Comment: If `parse` never returns `null` in the successful case, that’s a good solution. An alternative would be to let `parse` return an `Optional<String>`, but before Java 9, the stream code would not look better than what you already have. Starting with Java 9, you could use `.flatMap(s -> parse(s).stream())` then.

Comment: Good point. But I would split your `.flatMap(s -> parse(s).stream())` into two steps like `.map(this::parse).flatMap(Optional::stream)`. IMHO this is easier to read.

Comment: I actually consider to use Optional but doing .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get) is a lot more to read that just .filter(Objects::nonNull) but yes it may cause someone in the future to reuse my method and take a null pointer to the chin. By the way java 9 and 10 are not supported by oracle anymore, I assume that optional flatmap optimization would work with java 11, is that correct?

Comment: Of course, it will work in Java 11 too. For Java 8, you may create a helper method, `public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Optional<T> o) { return o.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty); }`. Then, you can use a solution close to the Java 9+ variant, `.flatMap(s -> stream(parse(s)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me your way of skipping `null` elements is pretty good.

However if you want to do it in functional way, then avoid returning `null` at all. Return an `Optional` instead:

```
public Optional<String> parse(String s){
    try{
        return Optional.of(<parsed_value>);
    } catch (Exception e ){
        log(e);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

**Java 1.8** solution:

```
public List<String> validator(List<String> values) {
     return values.stream()
                  .map(this::parse)
                  .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                  .map(Optional::get)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Java 1.9+** solution: (as proposed by *@Holger* already):

```
 public List<String> validator(List<String> values) {
     return values.stream()
                  .map(this::parse)
                  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```